# Dynamic Type for Differing Inputs in .Net Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Wondering what the best approach is to accept either a string or array of strings as the input for a .Net Core 3.1 web API. Example inputs would be.

```
{
  "name":"First Last",
  "caseId":"uuid4"
}
```

Or

```
{
  "name":"First Last",
  "caseId": ["uuid4-case1", "uuid4-case2"]
}
```

The primary motivating factor to this approach is to version the existing records from a single caseId to multiple caseIds over time. The database backing this API happens to MongoDB and records exist with both types of values. We could update the model to use two fields to represent the difference, but just wondering if it possible.

One option we looked at was using a dynamic property on the input model but this led to deserializing the property and then type checking based on the ValueKind value.

Mainly looking to see if there is a standard approach to this kind of use case, or if it's frowned upon with .Net Core to accept multiple types for a property on input. Couldn't find a good example, hence the ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Generally you want to avoid changing the structure of the API, as it means that (theoretically) your users have to change the way in which they interact with the API. Ideally, if possible, I'd recommend leaving the API 'as is', and allowing the users to upload multiple cases client-side. You can always *store* them separately server-side, and link them either with their `name` or with a bridging table.

The best server-side change would be to version the API, providing different endpoints. The user would then be able to upload a string to `/api/v1`, and a string array to `/api/v2`. The advantage of this is the backwards-compatibility; your original `v1` endpoint will now *never change*, and any consumers will still be able to use it without changing the structure on their end. Obviously, this means that all consumers who want to use the new structure will have to hook up to a different endpoint, which could add complexity if you're not in control of all of the consumers.

The *other* option is the one you propose - allowing a flexible data type. In this case, you could check based on the type of the variable with `.GetType()`:

```
if (_variable.GetType() == typeof(string))
{
    // Original logic
}
else if (_variable.GetType().IsArray)
{
    // Split logic
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. For the moment we added another field on the model to handle single vs multiple id values being present, but may double back and refactor with the above. The API has been in use with the `string` input and a requirement change is driving the update to a `list` type. I think the thing that was least straightforward was using .Net Core and the model binding from MVC, how do you accept a single input model that has a property whose type may vary? Which is where the dynamic type attempt originated.